# Controller called twice when used with angular material tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

My controller gets called twice when I am using angular material tabs.

The tabs:

```
<div layout="column" flex="">
  <md-content id="content">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom="" md-autoselect="">
      <md-tab label="Home" ui-sref="home">
        <div ui-view=""></div>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Contact" ui-sref="contact">
        <div ui-view=""></div>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

The controllers:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.contact')
        .controller('ContactController', ContactController);

    function ContactController() {
        var vm = this;

        activate();

        function activate() {
          console.log('Contact Controller');
        }

    }
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.home')
        .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

    function HomeController() {
        var vm = this;

        activate();

        function activate() {
          console.log('Home Controller');
        }

    }
})();
```

The states:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
    ])
        .config(configBlock);

    function configBlock($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "home.html",
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('contact', {
            url: "/contact",
            templateUrl: "contact.html",
            controller: 'ContactController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
    }

})();
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ro2J4Q5jv329sIeHuXTH?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, because you are using ui-view two times.

Comment: Even if <ui-view> was used once, the controller would have been called twice. I am also encountering this problem. Looking for some good explanation and solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i also hav the same issue 
use the ng-include instead of the ng-view

```
<md-tab label="Issues" >   
    <ng-include src="'/app/src/project/task/task.tpl.html'"></ng-include>
    <!-- <div ui-view></div> -->
</md-tab>
```